# Volley not calling getParams() for standard POST request

Tags: android, android-volley

I am trying to post some parameters to my rails API using Volley in Android. This is the code:

I tried with two log statements, one in `getParams()` and another in `getHeaders()`. The one in `getHeaders()` is logged while the other one is not. Why is volley ignoring `getParams()`?

```
{
//full_name,email,password are private variables defined for this class

String url =  "http://10.0.2.2:3000/users/sign_up.json" ; 

JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                 url, null,
                 new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                     @Override
                     public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                         Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                         pDialog.hide();
                     }
                 }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                     @Override
                     public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                         VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                         pDialog.hide();
                     }
                 }) {

             @Override
             public Map<String, String> getParams() {
                 Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

                 //This does not appear in the log
                 Log.d(TAG,"Does it assign params?") ;


                 params.put("name", full_name.getText().toString());
                 params.put("email",email.getText().toString());
                 params.put("password", password.getText().toString());

                 return params;
             }
             @Override
             public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {

                 //This appears in the log  
                 Log.d(TAG,"Does it assign headers?") ;

                 HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                 headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

                 return headers;
             }

         };

        // Adding request to request queue
        VHelper.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq, tag_json_obj);

}
```

Comment: It's quite easy to solve, check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24402403/1294681).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Using StringRequest in place of JsonObjectRequest

```
StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url , new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Log.d(TAG, ""+error.getMessage()+","+error.toString());
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("id", "28");
            params.put("value", "1");

            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            headers.put("abc", "value");
            return headers;
        }
    };

        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(sr);
```

Comment: I can't believe this was it. I was using a JSONObjectRequest and the debugger never hit the getParams() method, so no POST params. The moment i changed to StringRequest the debugger hit the getParams(). ¬_¬

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day. Is there a reason why for JsonObjectRequest the overloaded getParams method is not getting invoked ?

Comment: The JsonObjectRequest is extended JsonRequest which override getBody() method directly, so your getParam() would never invoke,

Comment: Same here... Thank you!

Comment: thumbs up if you too got the problem

Comment: Can someone post the reason why JSONObjectRequest is not hitting getParams() but StringRequest is?

Answer (score 3):

The third parameter should be a JSONObject you do not need the getParams() method just pass them into the request.

```
 JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(
            method,
            url,
            jsonObjParams,    // <<< HERE
            responseListener,
            errorListener);
```

Comment: Hi sir, what if i will pass two parameters? how can i put it on the third parameters of JsonObjectRequest.?

Answer (score 3):

it happened because Volley params cache.

clean it like this

`requestQueue.getCache().clear();`

hope it's useful!

Comment: I tried this but didn't work to solve the issue of getParams() not being called. 
\n\n
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        queue.getCache().clear();

Answer (score 2):

I solved my issue by simply removing Content-Type from header :)

Answer (score 1):

Please override the getBody() method, and if your server can not handle JSON request parameter, you have to override the getHeaders() method to change your Content-Type.

Issue can found here: https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley/issues/82

Answer (score 1):

For JSONobjectRequest the getParams() doesn’t work for POST requests so you have to make a customRequest and override getParams() method over there. Its because JsonObjectRequest is extended JsonRequest which overrides getBody() method directly, so your getParam() would never invoke. To invoke your getParams() method you first have to override getBody(). Or for a simple solution you can use StringRequest.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `shouldCache(false)` for your request object before you add it into queue.

Answer (score 0):

To provide `POST` parameter build a `JSONObject` with your POST parameters and pass that `JSONObject` as a 3rd parameter. `JsonObjectRequest` constructor accepts a `JSONObject` in constructor which is used in Request Body.

```
JSONObject paramJson = new JSONObject();

paramJson.put("key1", "value1");
paramJson.put("key2", "value2");


JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,url,paramJson,
    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

        }
    },
    new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem 
I solved it using clear queue Cache

```
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
requestQueue.getCache().clear();
requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

just use requestQue.getCache().clear();

Answer (score 0):

If you do a Post using Android Volley, it should call the methods getHeaders(), getBody(), **getParams()**, and getBodyContentType() in that order.

If you do a GET request using Android Volley, it should call the methods getHeaders() only.

Answer (score -1):

if you use My Singleton try this:

```
MyVolley.getInstance(this).getRequestQueue().getCache().clear();
```

Maybe you use cache on your code