# How to make a Json Array Request with Request Parameters

Tags: android, android-volley

I have to make json array request with the following request paramatetrs.

```
[
  "Login",
  {
    "password": "",
    "username": "",
    "ip": "12.123.124.12",
    "login_type": "Android"
  }
]
```

I use volley to make post request. In volley, if we have to make jsonarrayrequest, we do something like the following,

```
  JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(Constants.requestUrl,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                pDialog.hide();
            }
        });
```

The problem is that, How can I ever be able to insert my request parameters in the above code snippet. In case of JsonObjectRequest, we have provision to insert as follows,

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, Constants.requestUrl, frameLoginJson(),
                new Response.

Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        hideDialog();
                        error.printStackTrace();

                    }
                }
        );
```

In frameLoginJson, im framing the request parameter and dispatching the request.

But Im unable to do the same in case of JSONArrayRequest. How can I be able to make json array request with request parameters using volley especially or by any other mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to override the [getParams method](http://afzaln.com/volley/com/android/volley/Request.html#getParams()) with the following signature: `protected Map<String,String> getParams()`.

Here's an example:
see the answer to [Volley not calling getParams() for standard POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24284651/volley-not-calling-getparams-for-standard-post-request)

Comment: can you please elaborate with reference to my code?