# Calling method from getParams()

Tags: java, android

I am trying to call a method from getParams() , but nothing happens , is it the right way to call from getParams() or wrong? this method `getDrugId(drugNames.get(i));` returns a value , but when i put it inside getparams(); nothing happens.

```
{
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    for (int i = 0; i<drugNames.size(); i++){

                        params.put("drid["+i+"]",getDrugId(drugNames.get(i)));
                        params.put("paid", 1+"");
                    }



                    return params;
                }
```

```html
private String getDrugId(final String drugName) {



        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Config.ROOT + Config.GETRUGSIDS, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {


                    drID=response.trim();
//                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "time out Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "no Connection Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Authenticatin Failure Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Network Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Server Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "JASON Parse Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

                params.put("drNAM",drugName);

                return params;
            }
        };

        MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
        return drID;
    }
```

Comment: can u share the whole code

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the method `getDrugId(drugNames.get(i));` without doing anything with the result.

You're probably supposed to use the result as index, like this, right?

```
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                for (int i = 0; i<drugNames.size(); i++){

                    params.put("drid["+getDrugId(drugNames.get(i))+"]",drugNames.get(i));
                    params.put("paid", 1+"");
                }



                return params;
            }
```

Comment: its like this params.put("drid["+i+"]",getDrugId(drugNames.get(i)));

Comment: Before putting values into params map, you're calling method getDrugId(drugNames.get(i)); but not doing anything with the result, why is that?

Comment: I called the method "getDrugId(drugNames.get(i)))" to get " drugId value" from mysql , by sendeng the name of the drug , i will post the full code

Answer (score 0):

`getDrugId(drugNames.get(i));`This is supposed to return some value,right? But you are nowhere assigning the value that the method call is returning you in your code as it looks. Also, could you debug and check what `getDrugId(xxx)` is returning if you think of utilizing what this method call returns.

Comment: I have debugged the method and it returns a value , but when i put it inside getparams() nothing happenes

Comment: You can refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24285544/android-volley-http-request-custom-header/24402403#24402403 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24284651/volley-not-calling-getparams-for-standard-post-request